# .htaccess force to SSL and remove filename extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I am trying to rewrite my URL at the moment using .htaccess basically I want to force all connections to https:// and also remove any trailing .html extensions.

Here is what I have so far,

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.%{HTTP_HOST}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This forces the user to use https but it does not remove the .html from the URL where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional rule to strip off `.html` from URLs. Moreover you can combine that rule and `www` and `https` rules into one to **avoid mumtiple 301 redirects**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:\.html)?$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```